# execute all files under a directory with sed and find

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, sed, find

I'm trying to use `find` to execute all the files under a directory. I have a `sed` script that will replace all instances of `#` with `//`.

Assume my directory is `/path/to/directory` and it contains `file1`, `file2`, `file3`.

Using `find` and `sed`:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec sed -f file.sed {} \;
```

How do I make it to run ALL files (`file1`, `file2`, `file3`) under `path/to/directory`?

Comment: Is this some sort of an assignment that you absolutely have to use `find`, `-exec` and `sed`? Or other possible more elegant solutions will also do?

Comment: i prefer to use `find -exec and sed` but im open to other solution as well

Comment: Essentially the same thing crossposted multiple times here [Execute sed on all file under a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611930/execute-sed-on-all-file-under-a-directory), [Execute sed on all file under a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611930/execute-sed-on-all-file-under-a-directory), [How to use -exec option with 'find'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611891/how-to-use-exec-option-with-find)

Answer (score 1):

Your `find` command looks fine and should work, provided that the `sed` command in `file.sed` is correct. Since you don't show us your `file.sed`, we can't be sure that it is correct, so here is what its contents should look like for replacing all instances of `#` with `//`:

```
's|#|//|g'
```

Notice that `|` is used as a delimiter instead of `/` for readability purposes (we dont' have to escape each of the `/` for the replacement).

What you also need to do is to modify the files in place using the `-i` `sed` flag.

So your command should be:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec sed -i -f file.sed {} \;
```

For such a simple replacement, however, using a `sed` file seems like an overkill. In this case I would run the `find` command as:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec sed -i -e 's|#|//|g' {} \;
```